# dynamically rotating based on mouse movement is janky

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I've got a webpage that has a fish following the mouse and looking at it. for this I'm using mainly JS and some CSS transitioning.

Sadly the fish does a weird spasm when the mouse goes to the left of the fish (due to it being flipped around so it keeps the underside to the bottom), and whenever the mouse moves past the fish's x-axis the fish does an entire 360 degree turn which is also an issue I wasn't able to solve.

```js
const fish = document.querySelector("div.vis-follow");
const fishTurn = document.querySelector("div.vis-turn");
let mouseX = 0;
let mouseY = 0;
let fishX = 0;
let fishY = 0;
let speed = 0.001;

function animate() {
  let distX = mouseX - fishX;
  let distY = mouseY - fishY;

  fishX = fishX + (distX * speed);
  fishY = fishY + (distY * speed);

  fish.style.left = fishX + "px";
  fish.style.top = fishY + "px";

  const fishCenter = getCenter(fishTurn);
  let angle = Math.atan2(mouseY - fishCenter.y, mouseX - fishCenter.x);

  // fishTurn.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}rad)`;

  if (mouseX < fishX) {
    fish.style.transform = `scaleY(-1)`;
    fishTurn.style.transform = `rotate(${-angle}rad)`;
  } else {
    fish.style.transform = `scaleY(1)`;
    fishTurn.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}rad)`;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function getCenter(element) {
  const {
    left,
    top,
    width,
    height
  } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: left + width / 2,
    y: top + height / 2
  }
}

animate();

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  mouseX = event.pageX;
  mouseY = event.pageY;
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.cls-1 {
  fill: #fcfdff;
}

.cls-2 {
  fill: #ff5a5f;
}

.cls-3 {
  fill: #963538;
}

.cls-4 {
  fill: #9c9d9e;
}

.cls-5 {
  fill: #cfcee6;
}

.cls-6 {
  fill: #0d454c;
}

div.vis-follow {
  width: 40px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: center;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

div.vis-turn {
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div class="vis-follow">
  <div class="vis-turn">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 193.11 91.96">
      <defs>
        .cls-1 { fill: #fcfdff; }
        .cls-2 { fill: #ff5a5f; }
        .cls-3 { fill: #963538; }
        .cls-4 { fill: #9c9d9e; }
        .cls-5 { fill: #cfcee6; }
        .cls-6 { fill: #0d454c; }
      </defs>
      <g id="Laag_2" data-name="Laag 2">
        <g id="Laag_1-2" data-name="Laag 1">
          <path class="cls-1" d="M119.55,92,190,51.29a6.13,6.13,0,0,0,0-10.62L119.55,0Z" />
          <polygon class="cls-2" points="119.55 0 39.85 45.98 119.55 91.96 119.55 0" />
          <g>
            <polygon class="cls-1" points="0 68.97 39.85 45.98 0 22.99 0 68.97" />
            <polygon class="cls-4" points="0 68.97 39.85 45.98 0 45.98 0 68.97" />
          </g>
          <polygon class="cls-3" points="39.85 45.98 119.55 91.96 119.55 45.98 39.85 45.98" />
          <path class="cls-5" d="M119.55,46V92c48.5-29.32,72.66-37.69,72.7-46Z" />
          <circle class="cls-6" cx="147.75" cy="45.62" r="6.11" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I placed your code in to an executable snippet, however it doesn't work as the HTML is missing the `.vis-follow` element. Can you please edit the code to include it.

Comment: I think I might've missed one when uploading it here, it should work now!